# What type of Sansevieria is this?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, plant-recommendations, succulents, snake-plants

[image: Sansevieria]

Does anyone know what type of Sansevieria is this? The foliage looks like Sansevieria Cylindrica, but I have only seen starfish shape or straight-up shape before. The layering of foliage looks a bit like Haworthia Fasciata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Sansevieria francisii* 'Ouch' Spiky Mother in Laws Tongue.